# How can i access data in Excel sheet using vb?

Tags: vb.net, excel, binding

Am devoloping a windows form application which need to retreive a particular column from Excel sheet and i want to display that data in a dropdown menu.
As i am newbie to Visual Basic please explain end to end process with code.
Thanks,
Snehal

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Microsoft Office Interop. You can find an example at http://dotnetperls.com/excel

Also, this page at [C-Sharp Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/howtooepnandreadanexcelspreadsheetinalistviewin.net11282005034134am/howtooepnandreadanexcelspreadsheetinalistviewin.net.aspx) might be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I was typing more detail, but that link has all the basics.